# How to generate CSR for multi-domain (UCC) purchased SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, csr, ucc

I have a set up for 4 domains/subdomains running on 4 Nginx servers on 4 different instances:

- `www.example.com`
- `ai.example.com`
- `cms.example.com`
- `submissions.example.com`

I have purchased UCC Multiple Domain certificate from Godaddy for these subdomains
Each of these subdomains is hosted on a separate server.

How do I generate a CSR which will account for each of the subdomain on the different servers?

The CSR I have right now is for the root domain `example.com`, but it does not seem to be working: only working on the subdomain server (AWS instance) where I have generated the CSR but not on another subdomain on another instance even though I have added the subdomains to the SAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you complete the domain validation for all domains?

If yes, to install the UCC on multiple servers, export the private key from the original server and import it on the additional servers you want to secure. Then, install the UCC on the new servers.

Source: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4649/adding-or-dropping-subject-alternative-names-from-ucc-certificates